# Design for Multiple Screen on Android

Tags: android, screen

I'm new in the world of Android development. I don't understand how to support all devices screen. My question is that: i've a horizontal logo, not vertical, that have two different dimensions for width and height. How i choose the perfect resolution and dimension for this? And what kink of tool i need to use for this operation? (Can I use PS?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please follow this guide line for multiple screen support [Click here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)